# How can I add bootstrap's form-control class for the Ruby on Rails collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

I have a `collection_select` tag where the user can select which web user to assign on for the ticket. The items on the `collection_select` will come from the database.

How can I add the bootstrap's `form-control` class to this `collection_select` tag?

I tried this code:

```
<%= f.collection_select :web_user_id, WebUser.all,:id,:email, include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

but it didn't work. I also read these [Ruby on Rails 5.2.0 documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select), but that didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_select :web_user_id, WebUser.all,:id,:email, {prompt: "Select web users"}, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Try this it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your code into :

```
<%= f.collection_select :web_user_id, WebUser.all,:id,:email, {}, { :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control' } %>
```

It's part of the the method's html_options. See https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select for further infos.

You need to first set the `options = {}`, as empty braces at least `{}`.

Then, you can set your `include_blank` and `class` between the second braces (`html_options = {}`).

The final form should be like including `{}, { :include_blank => true, class: 'form-control' }`

Comment: Did you check in the web inspector if the `form-control` class is present or not on the field ?

Comment: Also, does your interface or theme use Boostrap, as `form-control` is part of it ?

Comment: yes, it's not present on the field. Here, check what happened: https://snag.gy/rfav17.jpg

Comment: Try with this new edited version of my answer. It was missing `{}` before `{:include_blank ...'

Comment: Are you using form_for or simple_form?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `{}` after `:email` like

```
<%= f.collection_select :web_user_id, WebUser.all, :id, :email, {}, include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

and see the generated HTML

```
<select include_blank="true" class="form-control" name="web_user[web_user_id]" id="web_user_web_user_id">
    <option value="20">avcd@example.com</option>
    <option value="21">sa@example.com</option>
</select>
```